# How can I move VS Code's Activity Bar to the bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I move the activity bar of VS Code to the bottom? Is there any possibility or some kind of mod?
I have a vertical monitor and width space is precious so for me, i am more interested in moving such things to the bottom or the top.

[image: This is the Activity Bar, right now it's on the left side of the window.]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Install the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension.
- In your `settings.json` add `"workbench.useExperimentalGridLayout": true,`.
- In `Settings (UI)` go to the Customize UI settings and set `Activity Bar` to `"bottom"`.
- Completely close VSCode and reopen.

[image: sidebar on bottom of vscode]

Comment: This doesn't allow hiding of the windows, though. In some ways its actually worse.

Comment: Just to be clear this will only move the icons at the bottom. This is not a solution for me as te actual content of the menu is what takes the space, not the icons.

Comment: @lenz the content of what menu?

Comment: The explorer, for example. I'd love for the actual file tree to be moveable to the bottom. On a vertical screen it's hard to navigate as is.

Comment: Got it. Not really a downvote worthy reason as it isn't part of the question  but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @ZakA.Klajda I'm a bit late but you can hide the sidebar with `ctrl+b` keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yea, that's really not a solution for vertical monitors. Maybe we should write a plugin for it, it's such a necessary feature.

Comment: It's been suggested [in a comment posted as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75148153/5211833) that "Do not use the suggestion which @GollyJer suggested. It will break your VS Code, forcing you to completely wipe & re-install it (losing all of your extensions in the process)."

Comment: Customize UI is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of important notes and issues which may affect your desire to use the new setting (as mentioned by starball):

```
Workbench > Activity Bar : Location        default/top/bottom/hidden
```

To actually color theme the activity bar when it is at the `bottom` (or `top`) you use these `colorCustomizations`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    // activityBar Top or Bottom theme colors
    
    "activityBarTop.background": "#8cad8c",
    "activityBarTop.activeBorder": "#000",
    "activityBarTop.activeBackground": "#000",
    "activityBarTop.foreground": "#fff",
    "sideBarActivityBarTop.border": "#000",
    "activityBarTop.inactiveForeground": "#ff0000"
}
```

Unfortunately there is an issue where `"activityBarTop.foreground"` and `"activityBarTop.inactiveForeground"` do NOT currently work for an activity bar icon below the Secondary Side Bar.

Also having the activity bar at the bottom does not play well with this setting:

```
Window : Menu Bar Visibilty     compact
```

that normally puts a hamburger menu on the Activity Bar that contains the File/Edit/Selection/etc. options.  That hamburger icon will be put in the bottom activity bar location but does not function properly.

[image: Activity Bar Bottom issues]

The gif above also shows the Activity Bar icon for `Debug` under the Secondary Side Bar on the right, but the foreground color is not working for the active or inactive state.

Also note that if you have moved a view to the Secondary Side Bar - like `Run and Debug` in the example above - closing the secondary side bar does NOT move that icon back to the main Activity Bar under the Primary Side Bar - you have to reopen the Secondary Side Bar to see that icon again.

[GH: ActivityBar bottom and Window: Menu Bar Visibility don't work well together](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/208258)

[GH: Activity Bar: bottom - active and inactive foreground theme colors are ignored](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/208259)

---

Previous Answer:

I don't think there is a direct way to move the activity bar to the bottom, but there is an extension [activitus bar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.activitusbar) which will move the activity bar icons to the status bar and then you can hide the activity bar.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code 1.88 supports bottom positioning, like `"workbench.activityBar.location": "bottom",` in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

Release notes section: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_activity-bar-at-the-bottom.

Pre-1.88, without using extensions, not to the bottom, but in VS Code 1.84, you can move the activity bar to be a horizontal tab strip in the primary sidebar. The relevant issue ticket is [Support showing the activity bar in alternate layouts #118692](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118692), implemented by PR [Support activity bar on top of primary side bar #195067](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/195067). You can right click the activity bar, and the context menu will have a dropdown item called "Activity Bar Position", where you can select "Side", "Top", or "Hidden". It just controls a setting named `workbench.activityBar.location`, which has the options `"side"`, `"top"`, and `"hidden"`.